# Flattening a stream in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have this datatype:

```
datatype 'a stream' = Susp of unit -> 'a stream
and 'a stream = Empty | Cons of 'a * 'a stream'
```

and I want to write a flatten function which has the type below.

```
flatten: ’a stream’ stream’ -> ’a stream’
```

The flatten function will take stream of streams as input and flatten it by appending them.

How do I do this? Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I know how to do it for lists. It is quite simple:
`fun flatten [] = [] | flat (l::ls) = l @ flatten ls;`
Help me with streams please, I don't know how to pattern match a stream of a stream.

Comment: I assume this is homework. I suggest you first try to flatten a 'a list list, and then adapt it to streams.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, I know how to do it for lists. It is quite simple: `fun flatten [] = [] 
  | flat (l::ls) = l @ flatten ls;`
Help me with streams please, I don't know how to pattern match a stream of a stream.

Comment: You pattern match as usual: `fun flatten Empty = ... | flatten (Cons(x,xs)) = ...`. You also need to define `append` on streams. The only remaining trick is inserting `fn` in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write it for `list` first:

```
fun append(xs, ys) = case xs of
    [] => ys
  | (x::xs) => x :: append(xs, ys)              

fun flatten(xss) = case xss of
    [] => []
  | (xs::xss) => append(xs, flatten(xss))
```

The above should be obvious. Now we only need to change it slightly to support `stream`, by `Susp`ending and `force`-ing at the appropriate steps:

```
fun force(Susp(xs)) = xs()                                        

fun append(xs, ys) = case force xs of
    Empty => ys
  | Cons(x,xs) => Susp(fn () => Cons(x, append(xs, ys)))

fun flatten(xss) = case force xss of
    Empty => Susp(fn () => Empty)
  | Cons(xs,xss) => append(xs, flatten(xss))
```